# Entity Framework Core does not create a right script for my database correctly

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, mariadb

I have an issue where Entity Framework doesn`t successfully create and update my database schema.

I only have 1 migration added right now called "InitialMigration".

The migration has the correct .Designer.cs that matches with the ModelSnapshot.

I tried updating the database using the dotnet ef database update InitialMigration, and I see it updated successfully, but I only see the Migrations table.

When I run the "dotnet ef migrations script" i get this output:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` __EFMigrationsHistory`(`MigrationId`varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,`ProductVersion`varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT`PK___EFMigrationsHistory `PRIMARY KEY (`MigrationId`)
) CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4;

START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO `__EFMigrationsHistory` (`MigrationId`, `ProductVersion`)
VALUES ('20231119014754_InitialMigration', '7.0.10');

COMMIT;

`
Im applying the configuration from assembly usint IEntityTypeConfiguration interface.

Properties of AppDbContext, it extends the DbContext class

```
public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; } = null!;
public DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; } = null!;
public DbSet<Court> Courts { get; set; } = null!;
public DbSet<OutboxMessage> OutboxMessages { get; set; } = null!;

 public ApplicationDbContext() 
{
}

public ApplicationDbContext(
    DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) 
    : base(options)
{
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    string? connstring =
        "Host=dbaas-db-5110007-do-user-14547597-0.b.db.ondigitalocean.com; Port=25060; Database=defaultdb; Username=doadmin; Password=AVNS_9l1PkdtBRCQAEm1WbOu;";
    
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connstring,
            new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8,  0)), mysql =>
            {
                mysql.EnableRetryOnFailure();
            });
        optionsBuilder.EnableDetailedErrors();
        optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
    }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
}
```

Comment: What does your migration script have in the Up method?

Comment: Show your `DbContext` please.

Comment: @gunr2171 Up and down methods are empty..

Comment: I managed to solve the issue by deleting the ModelSnapshot and readding a migration.

Comment: Then mark it as closed, furthermore i really hope for you, that this password is not used in production...